# Algorithm for dividing sums of square roots: $\tfrac{\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{y_j}}$

Tags: divisibility, radicals

As a part of [a project](https://github.com/lycantropos/symba) for supporting symbolic computation of square roots (since using any sort of approximated calculation ends up accumulating errors after several iterations) I'm trying to implement an algorithm for division of sums of square roots, i.e. expression like
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{y_j}}
$$
where $x_i, y_j \in \mathbb{Q}$.
We can assume that $n > 2$ since $n = 1$ is trivial and $n = 2$ can be solved by multiplying both numerator & denominator by $\sqrt{y_1} - \sqrt{y_2}$.

For example if we have expression
$$
\mathrm{expr} := \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}
$$
when we square it
$$
\mathrm{expr}^2 = 2\sqrt{15} + 2\sqrt{10} + 2\sqrt{6} + 10
$$
and divide by the original one we should have it as a result of the division so
$$
\frac{2\sqrt{15} + 2\sqrt{10} + 2\sqrt{6} + 10}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}} = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}
$$

I think there is an algorithm for this particular task (since [*WolframAlpha* is capable of doing so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282sqrt%2815%29+%2B+2sqrt%2810%29+%2B+2sqrt%286%29+%2B+10%29+%2F+%28sqrt%282%29+%2B+sqrt%283%29+%2B+sqrt%285%29%29)), but I couldn't find it online, so any help would be appreciated.

## Edit

If I understood correctly [the approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4056102/609857) described by @Empy2 we can iteratively multiply by $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{y_j} - \sqrt{y_n}$, but this won't work for 4 terms, because after multiplication total number of terms will be $\tfrac{(n - 1)(n - 2)}{2} + 1$ which increases for $n > 3$.
For $n = 4$ we can multiply both numerator & denominator by $(\sqrt{y_1} + \sqrt{y_2}) - (\sqrt{y_3} + \sqrt{y_4})$ leading us to the case with $n = 3$, but that's it, for $n > 4$ I'm not aware of any working algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

$$f=\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5+\sqrt7+\sqrt{11}\\
g=(\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5+\sqrt7)^2-(\sqrt{11})^2\\
=6+2(\sqrt6+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{14}+\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{21}+\sqrt{35})\\
=2(3+\sqrt6+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15})+2\sqrt7(\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5)\\
=g_1+\sqrt7g_2$$

$$h=(g_1+\sqrt7g_2)(g_1-\sqrt7g_2)=g_1^2-7g_2^2\\
=4(40+10\sqrt{15}+12\sqrt{10}+16\sqrt6)-28(10+2\sqrt6+2\sqrt{10}+2\sqrt{15})\\
=-120+8\sqrt6-8\sqrt{10}-16\sqrt{15}\\
=(-120+8\sqrt6)-\sqrt5(8\sqrt2+16\sqrt3)\\
=h_1+\sqrt5h_2$$

$$k=(h_1+\sqrt5h_2)(h_1-\sqrt5h_2)=h_1^2-5h_2^2\\
=14400+384-1920\sqrt6-5(128+768+256\sqrt6)\\
=10304-3200\sqrt6\\
N=10304^2-6(3200)^2$$

Given $f(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$ in the denominator, let

$$g(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=f(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)f(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,-\sqrt5)\\
h(\sqrt2)=g(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)g(\sqrt2,-\sqrt3)\\
K=h(\sqrt2)h(-\sqrt2)$$

EDIT

$$f(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\sqrt{11})=f_1(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7)+\sqrt{11}f_2(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7)\\
g(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\sqrt7)=f(\sqrt{11})f(-\sqrt{11})=f_1^2-11f_2^2\\
=g_1(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)+\sqrt7g_2(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)\\
h(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)=g(\sqrt7)g(-\sqrt7)=g_1^2-7g_2^2\\
k(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=h_1^2-5h_2^2\\
m(\sqrt2)=k_1^2-3k_2^2\\
N=m(\sqrt2)m(-\sqrt2)$$

Comment: it won't work for sum with 5 or more terms, because square of 4 or more terms will increase their number

Comment: Keep them as polynomials of $\sqrt2,\sqrt3$ etc rather than $\sqrt6$.  $g(x,y)=f(x,y,z)f(x,y,-z)$ has no odd powers of $z$ because it is unchanged when you replace $z$ by $-z$. So $g(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ has no $\sqrt5$,$\sqrt{10}$, or $\sqrt{15}$ etc..  In the same way, $g(x,y)g(x,-y)$ has no odd powers of $y$ so it gets rid of both $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt6$ and $h(x)h(-x)$ has no odd powers of $x$. So ends as an integer.

Comment: how these $g, h, ...$ will look like? I don't get it, also I've described in the edit section that multiplying by sum with negated terms won't work for $n > 4$